# How do I require and use a library from the Ruby Standard Library such as DateTime?

Tags: ruby, datetime, rvm, ruby-std

How do I require and use a library from the Ruby Standard Library such as DateTime?

I'm using [rvm](https://rvm.io).  I created a new project and specified which version of Ruby I'd like (in this case 2.1.0) and gave the project its own Gemset.

```
mkdir proj
cd proj
rvm use ruby-2.1.0
rvm gemset create proj
echo 'ruby-2.1.0' > .ruby-version
echo 'proj' > .ruby-gemset
touch proj.rb
```

I'd like *proj.rb* to require DateTime, make a new instance of a DateTime object, then exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as below

```
require 'date'
DateTime.parse '12Feb,2014'
```

You just need to write `require 'date'`, now you will be able to use all methods from the [`DateTime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) class API.

Comment: What's `pry`?  I don't have that on my system.

Comment: Ah, I see.  DateTime's parent is the Date class.  Thanks!

Comment: pry is a gem that can replace irb.. It's much better :-) Look it up